# Passing null parameters into LINQ where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table where some items may be null. I can query then easily by using a query like so:

```
db.SomeTable.Where(s => s.SomeCol == null)
```

Simple enough, but this does not work (No results. I suspect it is searching for an empty string instead; "") when using a variable that happens to be null, like so:

```
string variable = null;
db.SomeTable.Where(s => s.SomeCol == variable)
```

Do I have to do something special to get this to work?

Comment: What is the type of `SomeCol`?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting a compiler error or an exception?

Comment: is this EF of Linq2Sql? If EF, which version?

Comment: @Heather, I think he need to use DBNull.Value. (just to be more specific)

Comment: @Heather I think it's likely that that would not compile.

Comment: `==` is an operator which can't be used for arbitrary operands. I guess it's related to the type of `SomeCol` and `string`.

Comment: @Heather: A ORM is about hiding the database from the developer. Forcing him to use `DBNull` instead of `null` would go against this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using LinqPad you can see the difference.

The former creates a query like:

```
select ...
from SomeTable as t0
where t0.SomeCol IS NULL
```

whereas the latter is

```
select ...
from SomeTable as t0
where t0.SomeCol = @p0
```

Instead you can use object.Equals in your test.  E.g.,

```
string test = null;
var q = from c in SomeTable where object.Equals(c.SomeCol, test) select c;
```

This will generate the appropriate where clause based on the value of the variable used in the condition.

Comment: If this really is the case then that's yet another case where the abstraction of LINQ to SQL (or EF) is leaky. It's really a pity that there are so many cases, basically making the whole abstraction questionable.